# Video converting into mp3 on Java, Android

Tags: java, android

I need to convert mp4/flv files info mp3 in my Android application, but I don't know C/C++ and Android NDK. Do you know libraries/methods for easy converting on Java? Thank you for anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996433/decoding-video-and-encoding-again-by-mediacodec-gets-a-corrupted-file may be useful

Answer (score 0):

Your question is how to extract audio from MP4/ FLV files and save as mp3 file. Right ?

Then, very sorry, Android SDK does not provide any API for transformating or track extraction.

Also using available media framework to achieve the same is also not trivial (and even if you do, you will lose portability).

What I would suggest is to use your MP4 & FLV Parser to extract audio track, do transcoding (if audio track is non-mp3), and save the transcoded (if audio track extracted is mp3, then extracted data) data.

Or you can port FFMPEG code base and use the same. This again may be overkill for your small task.

Suppose you just want to extract mp3 track from MP4, then you understand the native mp4 parser and use the APIs for extraction. You may have to replicate some code from stagefright / opencore.

Shash

Comment: What MP4 & FLV parser are you referring to in this case?

Answer (score 0):

it's probably irrelevant for you anymore but if some one still need a mp4 to mp3 parser [here's an api that can do the job](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/)